# Gibbs free energy calculation for redox reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

I was wondering if it is correct to calculate the Gibbs free energy of reaction at $P = \pu{1 atm}$ and $T = \pu{1100 K}$ using the [NIST-JANAF thermochemical tables](https://janaf.nist.gov/). For example, for the reaction of ammonia and nitrous oxide:

$$\ce{NH3(g) + 1.5 N2O(g) -> 2 N2(g) + 1.5 H2O(g)}$$

Can I later use this result to calculate the electric potential knowing the amount of electrons transferred?

I'm no electrochemist, I'm just trying to estimate the open circuit voltage for a fuel cell.

Comment: You should always be able to compute open-circuit potentials from free energies.  I gather you know this and are asking about the appropriateness of your approach for computing free energies.  Is that what your question really is?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the formula and learnt how to use it. I would like to know if the way I am computing the free energies is correct.